# How to call webservice in java that created by wash_out gem

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, web-services, soap, wash-out

i build a web service project by wash_out gem ,i can call functions use the Savon gem ,but when i tried to connect to my webservice server by soap.jar in java; its doesn't work , how to write the url of functions? and how to send actions by get(default is post ,so rails will throw the routing error,because wash_out generate wsdl routes in GET way);
here is my code

```
class HxppController < ApplicationController



  soap_service namespace: 'urn:WashOut'


  soap_action "CreateOrUpdateDictionary",
              :args => {ZTYPE: :string, ZCODE: :string, ZDESC: :string },
              :return => {:ZRTN_CODE => :string, ZRTN_RESULT: :string}

  def CreateOrUpdateDictionary
    render :soap => {:ZRTN_CODE => "S", ZRTN_RESULT: "success"}
  end


end
```

My webservice url is localhost:3000/hxpp/wsdl  ；

how to fix this? thanks a lot